Generating PDF files with puppeteer when `link` tags are present
My website gives student a tools to create its own notes using RichText editor where the content might be pretty complex. I want to give him an opportunity to download these notes as pdf file. To do this I want to use puppeteer. I tested it by navigating to a certain page on my website and the result look very good. However, for these notes printing, I don't want to go to the specific page but just pass an html of a div that contains that notes. The problem is that if I do that, the styles are not preserved and the result looks veery bad. I'm using NextJS with Tailwind and many styles are added using link tags so I guess puppeter cannot now about them and thats why the styles does not work. What would be potential fix to make style works? My current use:


  async generatePdfFromHtml(user: UserEntity, data: InputGetPdfDto) {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ executablePath: puppeteer.executablePath('chrome') });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    const html = data.html;
    await page.setContent(html, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });

    console.log(html);

    const fileName = `element-${Date.now()}.pdf`;
    const filePath = path.join('output', fileName);

    await page.pdf({
      path: filePath,
      format: 'A4',
      printBackground: true,
      timeout: 0,
    });

    await browser.close();

    return filePath;
  }

MORE DETAILS
I have a rich website like this:
<html lang="en" class="dark" style="color-scheme: dark;">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/_next/static/css/app/layout.css?v=1717793996045" data-precedence="next_static/css/app/layout.css">

// content 

</html>

I want to add a button "Download as PDF" that will convert a div with id notes to a pdf file. I want to preserve all the styles that are originally on my website and are attached using link tags. Currently, my html is simply outerHTML of my div#notes. Obviously when I use page.setContent(html) the result looks awful becase of the missing styles. How to fix that?

Please share a [mcve]. There's not enough code here to help. What is html?

Hi, I added some details to my qestion

Thanks, although I don't have that CSS file. This code all looks fine to me basically. Using setContent loads the CSS. Are you running a web server? Any network errors in the console? My guess is that you're not running a server to serve the CSS file. You could also inline the styles into the HTML if you control the HTML, so there's no asset request to serve. BTW, never use timeout: 0. This suppresses useful debugging errors and causes your process to hang forever.

but the html looks like <div class="bg-card border text-red-8">...</div> so setContent have no idea about style tags and how to interpret bg-card for example. Thats my question how to solve this problem nciely. For now I think to replace all link tags by style tags but to do this I woull need to load all the css file and to the replacement. Any better ideas?

setContent absolutely knows how to interpret style tags. It runs the HTML page normally and loads all assets. Those classes are in your stylesheet though, which likely isn't being loaded. Please re-read my above response: are there errors in the network tab? If so, then your stylesheet isn't being loaded and you need to run a server. Please confirm that you're serving your assets. If you're not serving your assets, almost certainly, there's the problem--browsers can't read files off of disk directly due to security sandboxing. If you are running a server, your path to the asset may be wrong.

I'm not sure what's going on with your particular case, but if you use setContent, you're interpreting an HTML string in the browser. If that HTML string requests assets, the browser will attempt to retrieve them, but they can't be read from a local file directly; they must be served.
Here's a minimal example of the problem and solution.
make-pdf.js:
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^22.10.0

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  const html = await fs.readFile("test.html", "utf-8");
  await page.setContent(html, {waitUntil: "networkidle2"});
  await page.pdf({path: "test.pdf"});
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());

test.html:
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css"></link>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello World</h1>
</body></html>

test.css:
body {
  color: red;
}

Run node make-pdf and open test.pdf. You'll see there is no red text, indicating the CSS asset didn't load. That's expected, because we can't read from the file system, and we have no server hosting the file. Simply opening the test.html file in a browser and looking at the developer tools' network log will show the load failure.
Now run a web server in the working directory, like python http.server, change the asset to point to the hosted version:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:8000/test.css"></link>

Rerun node make-pdf and observe that the PDF now has a red background.
In production, point to your static file server which is probably same-origin, so no prefix is necessary. Your Puppeteer code can pass a flag into the HTML or use string replacement to set this URL based on the environment.
You can also host the HTML file itself on a server (why not, it's a static asset just like the CSS file) and navigate to it with goto rather than using setContent.
Alternately, if you control these files, inline the assets into the HTML file or use a templating engine like EJS to inject the relevant content from each file and use a single setContent built from all the resources. Here's a simple example that injects a string, but could inject file content just as readily.
You can also use page.evaluate() or page.addStyleTag() to add the correct style tag using a dynamic development/production path.

Since you're using Next.js, here's a complete, minimal example of one way to arrange this.
test.html and test.css are the same as above, except that the stylesheet has a localhost prefix added corresponding to the development server:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:3000/test.css">

I created a Next app with
npx create-next-app@^14.2.3 my-nextjs-app
cd my-nextjs-app
npm install puppeteer@^22.10.0

Here's the relevant folder structure:
.
├── next.config.mjs
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── pages
│   └── api
│       └── generate-pdf.js
├── public
│   ├── test.css
│   └── test.html

Here's generate-pdf.js:
import fs from "node:fs/promises";
import path from "node:path";
import puppeteer from "puppeteer";

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  let browser;
  try {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const [page] = await browser.pages();
    const htmlPath = path.resolve("public", "test.html");
    const html = await fs.readFile(htmlPath, "utf-8");
    await page.setContent(html, {waitUntil: "networkidle0"});
    const pdfBuffer = await page.pdf({format: "A4"});
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
    res.send(pdfBuffer);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
  } finally {
    await browser?.close();
  }
}

Run with yarn dev and visit http://localhost:3000/api/generate-pdf to see your PDF with red-colored text.
As with the non-Next example, the localhost prefix shouldn't be necessary in production, assuming your assets are on the same origin as Puppeteer.
See this answer for avoiding the slow networkidle0.
